# Cannot install classnames package (defined in package.json) automatically by npm

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I'm quite new to NodeJS and I'm facing **npm** problem for installing `classnames` package which is saved to `package.json` file.

Let say I have this `dependencies` list:

```
"dependencies": 
{
    "classnames": "^2.1.2",
    "jquery": "^2.1.3",
    "sleep": "^1.2.0",
},
```

Then, when I run `npm install`, only *jquery* and *sleep* are installed into `node_modules` folder, not ***classnames***. But, if I run manually `npm install classnames`, it does download that package to node_modules folder.

So, I can run my app on local by this workaround but when I deploy code to heroku, it cannot be installed either way and my app cannot run.

I tried to run `npm cache clean` but it does't help. Is it a problem from particular *classnames* package or anything else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I can solve this problem. It is not the issue only for *classnames* package.

The solution is to run `npm shrinkwrap` after I've installed all packages I want on local. Then commit all (especially including changes in ***npm-shrinkwrap.json***) and push to heroku.

The reasons have been explained clearly [here](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/02/27/managing-node-js-dependencies-with-shrinkwrap/). Quick review:

> When "npm install" installs a package with a npm-shrinkwrap.json file
>   in the package root, the shrinkwrap file (rather than package.json
>   files) completely drives the installation of that package and all of
>   its dependencies (recursively).